# Passing multiple scopes to Concern Method - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In the process of drying my Rails app code, I have created the following concern that is used to generate the contents of an index method.

```
define_method(:generate_index) do |string, scope|
   instance_variable_set( "@#{string}", string.camelize.constantize.public_send(scope))
end
```

I use this code to generate something like the following:

```
def index
    generate_index("foo", "all")
    # @foo = Foo.all
end
```

What I'd like to do is to have the define method accept a number of scopes. I tried passing in an array of scopes but that results in an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the splash `*` operator:

```
define_method(:generate_index) do |klass, *scopes|
  scope = klass.to_s.camelize.constantize
  scopes.each { |s| scope = scope.send(s) }

  instance_variable_set("@#{string}", scope)
end

def index
  generate_index(:foo, :all, :where_not_test)
  # @foo = Foo.all.where_not_test
end
```

Comment: will this not create multiple instance variables? What I'd like to achieve is creating something like "Foo.all.where_not_test". Not "Foo.all" and "Foo.where_not_test". Apologies if I am misunderstanding you.  Thanks.

Comment: @Herm: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Please see my updated answer.